# Joined Report Chart Issues

Tags: joined-reports

I created a joined report with two report types and a formula field for each report type in the joined report. When I try to create a chart that shows the two formula fields for some reason the report only shows one set of data. The Joined report is grouped by Account Name. Is there a reason why one group of data wouldn't show in the chart?

Thanks,
Dan